# Can you set clang-format's line length?

Tags: clang-format

clang-format is breaking up my lines at 80 columns. Is there a way to make stop breaking lines?  The [documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) doesn't seem to address this.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The configuration option responsible for it is called `ColumnLimit`. You can remove the column limit by setting it to 0.

```
ColumnLimit: 0
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It's set to 0 by default but is still breaking up lines at 80 width.

Comment: The default value is 80 because clang-format uses predefined LLVM style by default.
`clang-format --dump-config | grep ColumnLimit`
`ColumnLimit:     80`

Comment: No I just installed it on vscode and it was set to 0 by default. Leastways changing it to 0 doesn't fix anything so your solution doesn't work. I even tried rebooting vscode but at 0 it still splits every line at 80 characters.

Comment: I confirm, this **does not work** for VS Code on Linux (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 14):

Find `ColumnLimit` (under "Configurable Format Style Options" heading) on [that page](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#configurable-format-style-options) and you'll find the following statement:

> **ColumnLimit (unsigned)**
>
> The column limit.
>
> A column limit of *0 means* that there is *no column limit*. In this case,
> clang-format will respect the input’s line breaking decisions within
> statements unless they contradict other rules.

Source: Clang-Format Docs ([v4.0.0](https://releases.llvm.org/4.0.0/tools/clang/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html), [latest](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html)). Italics added for emphasis.

So, just like the docs say, set...

```
ColumnLimit: 0
```

... and you should be set.

Comment: It doesn't work. It's set to 0 by default but is still breaking up lines at 80 width.

Comment: Check your clang-format version. Also, make sure it's actually loading any config file you've set this in.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue too - I am using the C++ extension in VSCode and setting `ColumnLimit: 0` still wrapped at 80. I worked around this by setting `ColumnLimit` to a large number; I set `ColumnLimit: 200` and it works great.