# How to set comment's line length in clang-format?

Tags: c++, clang-format

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47683910/can-you-set-clang-formats-line-length), I know `ColumnLimit` can set code line length. But it also influences comment line length, and I don't wish it to be controlled by `ColumnLimit`.

How to specify comment line length when `ColumnLimit` has been set?

Comment: Unfortunately there's most likely no way to do this. The philosophy behind `ColumnLimit` is to make it fit on a specific screen. It doesn't make sense to make it fit on the screen, except for the comments.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I also have no this requirement before. But recently I am using emacs' lsp-ui, which can render comment in markdown in a separate frame as the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your comment correctly, you're saying that breaking comments into lines will hinder some functionality in some other code analysis program. In that case, you may turn clang format off and back on for part of your code:

```
// clang-format off
void codeThatWontBeFormatted() // my very long comment that won't be formatted
{
}
// clang-format on
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Actually, I have tried this solution before posting this question. But it will be a little annoyed when multiple function/class need be commented. Maybe I should write some elisp to automatically generate this snippet.